# Get arguments from URL

Tags: functions, urls, links

I have example link

```
http://mysite/login?user_id=6?reg=true
```

how get `user_id` and `reg` values form `$_GET`?

if i write:

```
echo ($_GET['user_id']);
```

Then get this:

```
6?reg=true
```

And i try :

```
echo get_query_var( 'user_id');
```

But not work. What i do wrong?

Comment: URL is not correctly generated. Share the code that resulted in this malformed URL.

Comment: mrben522 answer correctly. I must change '?' to '&'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL querystring is malformed.  `?` good before the first variable.  `&` goes before any others.  Your url should be `http://mysite/login?user_id=6&category=3`